# Unable to find the checkout page form

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

[image]

Hi am unable to find the **source code** of this file.

I want to change to **pin code** input type.
Where Can I find the checkout form page on guest checkout.
I searched in the template folder but could not identify the file.

Answer (score 0):

Go ti System >> Configuration >> Developer
switch to Main website (or your custom website view)
Debug >> Template Path Hints - Set it to yes and then reload page on frontend

you will see template path files

if site is in production you can litim Allowed IPs (comma separated) to your web ip address